# RadioGroup in expandablelistview

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button, expandablelistview

I'm trying to do something like this with expandable list view :

```
PARENT 1:
    - child 1 ( Radio Button)
    - child 2 ( Radio Button)
    - child 3 (Radio Button)
    - child 4 (Checkbox)
    - child 5 (Checkbox)
PARENT 2 ...
```

BUT: child 1,child2, child3 should act like a radiogroup. So if i check, for example, child2, child1 and child3 should be uncheked.

I've already managed to do this: some childs are  with radio button and some with checkboxes. But radio buttons are not connected with each other and don't act like a radio group.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

My XML code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="false"
    >

        <CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_row="0" />


        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
            android:paddingRight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingRight"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_row="0" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_column="2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>



</GridLayout>
```

Comment: If your Radio buttons is not grouped, then it would not make a sense of using the the Radio button. Maybe, if you could explain further what are you trying to achieve then we might be able to suggest further.

Comment: ok. my app is a calc of services. and a consumer chooses some servises ( he/she should check checkboxes) and app calculates the whole sum. But some servises are optional - i can choose or this one or another one. That's why i need radio-buttons that act like radio groups.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put them into a radio group. Look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Here is the example showed into the guide adapted to your task to do for each parent. (Personalize it with your needed attribute)

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/child1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/child2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/child3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RadioGroup>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/child4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<CheckBox android:id="@+id/child5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: the problem is that if i do such way every child will have 3 radio buttons in a row ;(

Comment: Just set orientation of RadioGroup to horizontal

Comment: my xml file is set that way that i have only one checkbox, one radio and 2 text view. And i use it for each row. In rows where should be checkboxes, i make radio-button invisible and vice versa

Comment: sorry i don't understand your question. My xml code is for static definition, if your app has variable quantity of this schema to define you have to create your layout programmatically. Write a function which create this schema and call it n-times with respective params

Comment: i don't understand your question anyway. Would you to put the 3 radioButtons in place of your <RadioButton.....>? Then take my <RadioGroup....> and replace it

Comment: When i do it i get each child with 3 radio buttons in a row

Comment: Change RadioGroup `android:orientation` from horizontal to vertical or vice versa and look at the result

Comment: did it. i have 3 horisontal radio buttons in every row

Comment: This is impossible. android:orientation="vertical" works for me

Comment: But why impossible? This layout shows how every child row should look like. If i add radio group with 3 radio buttons every row has it either.

Comment: ohhh now i understand what you are asking. Create them programatically under a signle RadioGroup and then assign each one to its GridLayout (or which parent should contain it)

Comment: What i have now - one child has 3 radio buttons, and i added essential text for   every button in xml file. BUT - the text of other child isn't shown and the sizes of children row has increased. So it's left to solve this problem - how to get back text. I think there is a mistake in xml file maybe

Comment: Remove all dinamic element from xml and set them programatically. Remember that the method .addChild() put the element to the tail of the parent.

Comment: Thanks! But what should i set programatically? Radio group and 3 radio buttons ?

Comment: Man you have serious problems on programming for Android ;) Have you to repeat your schema for N times? Do it programmatically. Have you a fixed number of times? Do it by xml. Java=dinamic, XML=static

Comment: i'm sorry..i'm just a beginner and it's difficult for me(

Comment: No problem ;) just start from the begin following some guide ;) (an up-vote for help would be appreciated)

Comment: I know you're gonna kill me..but could you again step-by-step write what i should do..i'm tryna do this during 3-4 weeks and don't get a success ;(

Comment: No man, i'm not here for write your code. I gave you the way to reach your scope, now is your turn to study how to accomplish each steps

Comment: Determinate what is static and what dinamic. Static element go into XML layouts, dinamic into Java files and link them to statics using the `@id` attribute of the parent

Comment: But how to distinguish static and dinamic?

Comment: statics have always the same value, dinamic can change over time or have to be defined in a way for consistence but linked in different place (i.e. your RadioButton)

Answer (score 1):

[https://gist.github.com/Psest328/8762232](http://saga-androidapplication.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-use-expandablelistview-using.html)

[How to use ExpandableListView using Check box](http://saga-androidapplication.blogspot.in/2011/05/how-to-use-expandablelistview-using.html)